# Stata: error factor variables and time-series operators not allowed

Tags: stata

I want to export data from Stata into a csv-file:

```
 outsheet "$dirLink/analysis.csv",  replace comma
```

but I got the following error message:

```
 factor variables and time-series operators not allowed
 r(101);
```

I couldn't find the solution in the net. Thanks for help.

Here are the variable definitions:

```
 tab0            str1   %9s                    
 linkid          float  %10.0g                 
 recid2          float  %9.0g                  
 recid1          float  %10.0g                 
 patient1        str28  %28s                   
 patient2        str9   %9s                    
 totwght         int    %10.0g                 
 status          str1   %9s                    
 fname           str13  %13s                   
 sname           str13  %13s                   
 doby            int    %10.0g                 
 cohort          str2   %9s    
 res1            str27  %27s                   
 res2            str29  %29s                   
 residence       str50  %50s   
 facility        str22  %22s                   
 maxwght         int    %10.0g
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax should be

```
outsheet using "$dirLink/analysis.csv",  replace comma
```

That is, the word `using` is required. This is documented in the help: no need for an internet search. It is true that the error message is not transparent, because Stata is guessing that you are trying something other than `using` or a variable list, either of which could follow `outsheet`.

P.S. in my answer to your previous question I pointed out that the correct spelling is Stata: see http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/resources/statalist-faq/#spell That's still true.

Comment: Thanks for help and sorry for the late answer. I was not only Stata beginner at that time but also SO-beginner.